# display text when hovering with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm new to jquery and attempting to display text when hovering over a div. I have a basic html page right now with a couple squares, one of which rotates when a button is clicked. Now, in this same square (div2) I'd like for some text to be displayed when hovering over this.

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<LINK href="divtest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=divtest.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="border">
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2">
</div> 
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="rotate()" />

<script>
$("id=div2").hover(
function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I identify that I want the text "HOVERING!!!" to be displayed over div2.

Here's the CSS

```
#border{
position:relative;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
border-color:black;
width:1366;
height:768
}

#div1{
position:relative;
background-color: blue;
display:block;
height:500px;
width:500px;
left:350px;
}

#div2{
position:relative;
background-color: green;
display:block;
height:400px;
width:400px;
top:50px;
left:50px;
}
```

And now for my .js page

```
var obj = "div2";
    var angle = 0;
    var interval = 100;
    increment = 5;

   function rotate() {
    $('#' + obj).css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        'msTransform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
        angle += increment;
        setTimeout(rotate, interval);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only id

```
$("#div2").hover(
```

instead of

```
$("id=div2").hover(
```

Comment: Changed it, nothing happened. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: No, that is the problem. I pasted your code into a jsfiddle and it works fine once that change is made (if you look at my post below). If its still not working, the problem is not in this code.

Comment: Ok, now it started working! I have no idea what was going on. I changed absolutely nothing, went back to close the page and then it worked.

Comment: @user1104854 possible the page was cached and when you went back the cache had expired.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to Makkesk8's suggestion, unless you have a really good reason to do so, don't use MouseOver and MouseOut if you're using jquery. Use MouseEnter and MouseLeave instead. [As explained on Ben Nadel's blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm), MouseEnter and MouseLeave will make your life a little easier. 

That said, you're on the right track with hover as it wraps MouseEnter and MouseLeave into one function. What you need now is two handlers in that one call. Your script should look more like this:

```
<script>
    $("#div2").hover(
function ()
{
    $(this).html($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
},
function ()
{
    $(this).html($(""));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $("#div2").hover(function () {
        $(this).append($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried it, no change. Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you use all of the code I provided? (even the .js and css)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#div2").hover(
function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
});
```

**OR**

```
$('div[id="div2"]').hover(
function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code (even fixed) will always append HOVERING!!! (again and again). 
See an example here for a version that only shows it once: http://jsfiddle.net/ggjbP/

Comment: This works, but it's "reversed." When you're not hovering it displays the text, and when you hover it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-->

JSFiddle (works on chrome/FF) --> http://jsfiddle.net/rt2800/Mab6g/

```
var obj = "div2";
    var angle = 0;
    var interval = 100;
    increment = 5;

   function rotate() {
    $('#' + obj).css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        'msTransform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
        angle += increment;
        setTimeout(rotate, interval);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div2").hover(
function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> HOVERING!!!!! </span>"));
});
$('#btnRotate').on('click', rotate);
                  })​
```

Comment: Hmm, nothings happening for me on jsfiddle, not even the rotating square. Maybe it's my computer, however, I don't see why the square still rotates when I'm just using firefox.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div id=div2><span></span></div>
<script>
    $("#div2").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find("span").text("HOVERING!!!!!");
        },
        function () { 
            $(this).find("span").text("");
        },
    );  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to ask for something by id is with `#`

```
$("id=div2")
```

should be

```
$("#div2")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qU4Z/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at OnMouseOver();

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: Won't mouseover leave the text even when the mouse is no longer over that div?

Comment: thats where OnMouseOut(); comes in :)